# SublimeLinter cppcheck linter executable not found

Tags: c++, sublimetext, sublimelinter

I have intalled SublimeLinter and sublimelinter-cppcheck packages to my Sublime Text 3.

The problem is that sublime text is saying `SublimeLinter: WARNING: cppcheck deactivated, cannot locate 'cppcheck'`. I figured out that cppcheck cannot find linter executable, so I decided that I will add path to linter to my system `$PATH` property. But the thing is that I cannot find linter executable on my system.

At first I thought that it's not installed but that I realised that it has to install with SublimeLinter package. But it did not. I tried to find it using Unix find command the only result is :

`/Users/syky/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.34.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/linter`

That is not what I am looking for.

I am using Sublime Text 3, Mac OS X Yosemite and ZSH as my shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SublimeLinter is looking for the [`cppcheck`](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net) executable, which you apparently haven't installed. It is not looking for a file named `linter`. Please ensure that you have completely read and understood the [`SublimeLinter-cppcheck` documentation](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-cppcheck) before proceeding. The easiest way to install `cppcheck` is either via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) (my personal favorite). Otherwise, you'll have to download and compile the source, which, if you're programming in C++, I assume you know how to do.

Once you have `cppcheck` installed, create a symlink to it in `/usr/bin` so Sublime can find it. Modifying your ZSH `PATH` won't do anything, unless you always launch Sublime from Terminal, because the `PATH` for programs launched from the Dock is different.

Comment: Awesome worked like charm all I needed to do was install cppcheck with homebrew. I thought that pre-compiled version of cpp comes with the `sublimelinter-cppcheck` package. Thanks!