# configuration of cppcheck linter in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, ubuntu-16.04, cppcheck, sublimelinter

I installed the `cppcheck` in my machine and `Sublimelinter` & `cppcheck` plugin in my `SublimeText3` as the documentation says but I am still unable to get the `cppcheck` working. I think I am doing some mistake in the path variable. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26366160/4774977) answer but couldn't understand. Please help me in configuring it. Thanks.

Here is my machine's (Ubuntu 16.04) output to relevant commands here:

```
which cppcheck
/usr/bin/cppcheck
```

my `~/.profile` file:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH:/usr/bin"
```

Here is my Sublimelinter.sublime-settings file:

```
{
    "user": {
        "debug": false,
        "delay": 0.25,
        "error_color": "D02000",
        "gutter_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/gutter-themes/Default/Default.gutter-theme",
        "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
        "lint_mode": "manual",
        "linters": {
            "cppcheck": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "enable": "style",
                "excludes": [],
                "std": ["c++11"]
            }
        },
        "mark_style": "outline",
        "no_column_highlights_line": false,
        "passive_warnings": false,
        "paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "python_paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "rc_search_limit": 3,
        "shell_timeout": 10,
        "show_errors_on_save": false,
        "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
        "syntax_map": {
            "html (django)": "html",
            "html (rails)": "html",
            "html 5": "html",
            "javascript (babel)": "javascript",
            "magicpython": "python",
            "php": "html",
            "python django": "python",
            "pythonimproved": "python"
        },
        "warning_color": "DDB700",
        "wrap_find": true
    }
}
```

> Also note that whenever I try to add /usr/bin/ above i.e. `"paths" : {"linux" : [/usr/bin/]}` Sublime shows me error. Please help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be just in your question, but your path you are adding to your Sublimelinter.sublime-settings file should be in quotes.

incorrect:

```
"paths" : {"linux" : [/usr/bin/]}
```

corrected:

```
"paths" : {"linux" : ["/usr/bin/"]}
```

Note: The adding paths section from [SublimeLinter Troubleshooting Guide](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#augmenting-path) states that if your PATH is initialized in the correct space (~/.profile for Ubuntu) that you shouldn't need to re-add the directory in the settings file. You should see the PATH output in the console if you turn on debugging for SublimeLinter and restart SublimeText

Comment: How silly of me? It was working fine. I was not looking on the console. Also I think I had settings in the linter in such a way that it was not allowing the mistakes to be visible on the screen. When I changed the mark style to `solid underline` the mistakes in the code started to appear as soon as I saved the file. I feel so naive here. Sorry for troubling you and thanks for the answer.

Comment: @SunilKumar Glad to here this was figured out. Please consider marking this as the correct answer.